# Read 2 columns from text file Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Hi I am trying to read a text file that has multiple rows. Let's say around 8. I need to extract only the first and second row of every line and perform some mathematical operation and write to a text file. I have written the code that can read 2 rows from all the line but when I try to write to the text file its writes only the last row.

I have used `json.dump` and also `savetxt` instead of `stdout` it still writes only the last row.

This the format of the text file, I need to extract only the highlighted text

```
1 **10.329978 74.70615** 9.0 0.0 0.0 -0.0327306505448 0.998721
2 **13.6538 94.96612** 0.0 5.0 0.0 -0.128285245646 0.9967
3 **139.9585 95.20927** 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.153868455786 0.9878
4 **10.2822 67.8397** 0.0 6.0 0.0 0.376976170355 0.92492
5 **57.398 11.017805** 0.0 4.0 9.0 0.563746473629 0.827
6 **58.831 27.58917** 1.0 5.0 2.0 0.775001606602 0.6741
7 **56.918 56.20145** 7.0 9.0 0.0 0.641212880548 0.7671
```

Here is my code

```py
#! /usr/bin/python

import math
import numpy
import csv
import json
import array
import sys

with open("calc.txt", "r") as file:
 x = 2
 y = 10

  for line in file:
  a = line.split()[1:3]
  list = [float(x) for x in a]
  list[0] = (list[0] - x)/0.1
  list[1] = (list[1] - y)/(0.1))
  new_arr = [list[0], list[1]] 
  sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'wt')
  print(new_arr)
```

Comment: you mean you need `10.329978 74.70615` and the asterisks are not present in the original file right?

Comment: yes, only the 1st and 2nd row

Comment: can mark one of the answers as accepted if they've helped you? If they did not, comment on what can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You store the result in a variable, then be out of the loop, you write to output.txt

```
#! /usr/bin/python

x = 2
y = 10
result = []

with open("calc.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:

        line = line.replace("**", "")
        a = line.split()[1:3]
        _list = [float(__) for __ in a]
        _list[0] = (_list[0] - x) / 0.1
        _list[1] = (_list[1] - y) / 0.1
        new_arr = " ".join([str(_list[0]), str(_list[1])]) 

        result.append(new_arr)

    file.close()


out_file = open("output.txt", "w")
out_file.write("\n".join(result))
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks you for your answer, but I am getting this error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.ndarray found, when writing out using join

Comment: I was edited my code, you can copy, save it to a file and run with python2

Answer (score 0):

Your code was perfectly fine except for the way you were writing to the new file. It should be `a+` instead of `wt`, in order to append to the file and not clear and write from beginning. Here's the fixed code:

```py
import sys

with open("calc.txt", "r") as file:
    x = 2
    y = 10

    for line in file:
        a = line.split()[1:3]
        list = [float(x) for x in a]
        list[0] = (list[0] - x)/0.1
        list[1] = (list[1] - y)/(0.1)
        new_arr = [list[0], list[1]] 
        sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'a+')
        print(new_arr)
```